# What does ARC do if I forcefully point an allocated object's pointer to nil?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I am allocating an object like

> A *a = [[A alloc] init];

At another point I am forcefully setting

> a  = nil;

Does it flash a message to ARC that the object can be released now?

Comment: I would say you just answered your own question. It fires the release method and if they retain count is zero it gets destroyed.

Comment: ooh...got it! If some other guy is still holding the object, it will not get released..rt? Thanks man!

Comment: @Advaith If somebody else "holds" the object, it won't get released. ARC is not magic, it just writes the retain/release messages in your code for you. Setting some variable to nil is nothing unusual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer - YES.
Once you set your object to nil it will get killed by Arc (most of the cases, from my experience you can lay your trust on ARC)

Dealloc methods in arc will be created for you. You must not make a dealloc call directly. However you can still create a custom dealloc method if you need to release resources other than instance variables. When creating a custom dealloc method, do not call the [super dealloc] method. This will be done for you and is enforced by the compiler.

You can read more about it [here](http://longweekendmobile.com/2011/09/07/objc-automatic-reference-counting-in-xcode-explained/)

Comment: Hey, I got a doubt there :-o What if same object is strongly referenced by 2 pointers and we assign one of the pointer to nil? In that case the object will not get released..rt?

Comment: It will receive a release call. but if another pointer holds a strong reference to that object it will not get removed out of memory as the retainCount is still 1

Comment: The object won't be killed by ARC but will receive a `release` call which decrements the objects retain count by one. Once the retain count drops to zero, the object will be killed. Every strong reference retains the object, incrementing the retain count by 1, so if you have 2 strong references to an object, its retain count will be 2, if you nil one of those references, it will drop to 1, but the object will still be there!

Answer (score 0):

I think the original object you were pointing at (an empty A object you created with alloc/init) will be released, but you can still use your "**a**" pointer, and make it point at another object.